# alguien podria darme un ejemplo para resolver {code: 499, message: 'Token Required', details: Array(0), authenticate: ƒ}

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy usando leaflet en laravel y envio esto y me dicel que hace falta tokens y cree la apikey pero no se donde colocarlo

```
geocodeService.reverse().latlng(posicion, 16).run(function(error, resultado) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(resultado);
  })
});
```

luego de esta funcion me manda el error